# Verify for $f(x,y)$, homogeneous of degree $n$: $xf_x+yf_y=nf$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

> $F(x,y)$ is homogenous of degree n if $f(tx,ty)=t^nf(x,y)$. Verify that
>
> - $xf_x(x,y)+yf_y(x,y)=nf(x,y)$
> - $x^2f_{xx}(x,y)+2xyf_{xy}+y^2f_{yy}(x,y)=n(n-1)f(x,y)$

---

*Looks like I need enlightenment again... Hopefully, its not another embarrassingly simple thing I missed out in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130419/prove-f-xyx-yfx-y-f-xx-yf-yx-y-for-a-separable-function-fx-y)*

What I tried:

$f_x(x,y)=t^nf_x(x,y)$

$f_y(x,y)=t^nf_y(x,y)$

$xt^nf_x(x,y) + yt^nf_y(x,y) = t^n(xf_x(x,y) + yf_y(x,y))$

Doesn't look like I am doing the right thing?

Comment: You can prove it by showing it is true for every monomial $x^k y^l$ (a direct calculation) and then argue by linearity that it folds for every polynomial $f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $g(t)=f(tx,ty)$. By the chain rule, $g'(t)=x f_x(tx,ty)+y f_y(tx,ty)$.

On the other hand, since $f$ is homogenous of degree $n$, we have $g(t)=t^n f(x,y)$ and so $g'(t)=nt^{n-1}f(x,y)$.

Now take $t=1$ and conclude that $x f_x(x,y)+y f_y(x,y) = g'(1) = n f(x,y)$.

For the second result you mention, consider $g''$.

Comment: This proof appears also in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html.

Comment: I think the part I don't get is why $g'(t)=x f_x(tx,ty)+y f_y(tx,ty)$? Or in the link, why is $x'=xt$, similar for $y'$

Comment: Also, how did you get $g(t)=f(tx,ty)=t^nf(x,y)$?

Comment: You get $g'$ using the chain rule. I've edited my answer to reflect this.